# convert cudaFuncSetCacheConfig to OpenCL way

Tags: cuda, opencl

I am trying to convert a CUDA benchmark to OpenCLbenchmark.
But I am currently stuck in converting `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig` to OpenCL.
As I searched on Google, I found that there is not a function in OpenCL, directly equivalent to `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig`.

So, I want to ask there is an alternative way to use that function in OpenCL?

Comment: Not possible from OpenCL indeed.

Comment: Also this is not portable and is against opencl isnt it?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use CUDA API calls to effect an OpenCL context, or *vice versa*. Therefore, unless a specific NVIDIA hardware feature is supported via a vendor specific extension (and in this case it apparently is not), there is no way to do this.